# Is there a way to smooth without making holes in a face?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, faces

First of all, I can't add or delete vertices or change vertex order because otherwise I'll mess up the UV mapping for this mesh, which I can't do anything about because it's applied by an external program (this is a skyrim model, the program is Outfit Studio).

This is what I'm dealing with. The left-hand side of the torso is all in one piece, but for whatever reason the right-hand side is multiple disconnected pieces. The unselected parts are the "seams" where the mesh splits.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/vUXAs]

This is what it looks like if I select everything.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/1wIKL]

And then if I apply smooth.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/ORkvr]

The left-hand side is fine because it's one piece, but if I smooth the right-hand side the pieces of the mesh end up shrinking. How do I get the right side looking like the left side without changing the vertices?

Comment: That looks like either deleted or hidden vertices. When you say "I smooth" what have you done exactly?

Comment: Do you see multiple meshes for that side of the clothing in the top right panel?

Comment: @lemon control+v — smooth

Comment: @jamie vetter, no it's one mesh that's split up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to me it lokes like you have double Vertices. You should make a copy file (just in case you mess it up) and select all Vertices with 'a' and on the left side you should have a panel (you can let it show up with 't', that's how it workes in blender). Select 'Tool' and under 'Mesh Tools' you should find the option 'Remove:' and there is the button 'Remouve Doubles'.

I hope that should fix it for you.
Gr W.Zayde

Comment: OK, W. Zayde is right... the first image shows that you has double vertices and they may be unconnected to the other part... +1!

Comment: Is there a method that doesn't involve adding or deleting vertices?